# Get value from dynamic href using jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to `Ajax`, `Jquery` & `PHP`. 
I am stuck in code I hope someone can guide me to resolve the issue:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#number_filters a').bind("click", function() {
    var year  = $(this).attr('href');
    $.post('getdata.php',{resultyear:year},function(res){
        $("#showresult").html(res);
    });
                return false;
  });

      });
    </script>

 Following code, if anyone click on link below, I am send a value by POST method to a php page and the returned data are displayed in DIV Tag:

<div id="number_filters">
<a href="1" class="c1">Link 1</a>
<a href="2" class="c1">Link 2</a>
</div>

 this is the div tag I use to display results from above code:

 <div id="showresult"></div>

 Up until now it has been working fine, and below is the output which I get from dynamic page:

 Output: 2015 2014 2013 2012 2011
```

Now my question is, if any one click on 2015 or 2014 I want to show again dynamic data retrieved database.

Can anyone give me some idea or code I can try to resolve the issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the output in you php file that generates the output like:

```
$output = "<a href='2015'>2015</a> <a href='2014'>2014</a>";
```

And update your jquery with this code:

```
$('#showresult').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var year = $(this).attr('href');

    // Ajax Request
    $.post(....);
});
```

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) helps you to achieve that you want.

Comment: Hello Jogesh, Thank You Sooooooooooooooo Much for providing good logic, God Bless you my dear....

Comment: @user3106824 glad to help you :), happy holidays